# Tamanho da imagem destacada no wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Tenho um loop que puxa a imagem destacada do post, eu puxo a imagem usando `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()`, tentei `get_the_post_thumbnail_url('thumbnail')` mas dá erro, preciso pegar a imagem em tamanho menor, só alertando que dessa forma dá certo `get_the_post_thumbnail_url()` mas a img vem em tamanho grande!

Comment: tenta sem este `get`, tente apenas `the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' )`

Comment: @PedroHenriqueKuzminskas assim ele puxa a img em tamanho thumbnail mas fica fora do array que eu puxo a img...

Comment: então faça assim `the_post_thumbnail_url( array(100, 100) );`, nos valores de "100" voce escolhe o tamanho.

Comment: não, o array é pra criar um json com os dados que eu puxo do wp...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[get_the_post_thumbnail()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/) aceita o tamanho como segundo parâmetro. O primeiro é o post_id

`get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $post->ID, 'post-thumbnail')` deve resolver

**Adendo**: tanto post id como tamanho são opcionais, e thumb é o tamanho padrão. Então na verdade se a chamada sem parâmetros está trazendo a imagem grande seu problema pode estar na geração dos thumbs, na hora do upload. já conferiu se as imagens reduzidas estão na pasta uploads?